# Powershell scripts works manually but not as a scheduled task

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have a powershell script that converts .doc to .pdf files. When I execute it manually, it works perfectly on my windows server 2012.

When I execute it as a scheduled task, opens an instance of Word, but cant close it, and the task don't end correctly. The worst part is that this process utilizes 10% of the procesor and when the task runs again, another one opens on top of it, and this keeps happening using 100% of the cpu.

Both times, manually and from scheduled task its runs as administrator... and the task is well created, if I modify the script and dont open a Word and just for example create a .txt file, works fine. so the problems its there. "opening word from task scheduler"

Here's the scripts, and also screenshots. Any help will be appreciated!

```
$origen = 'C:\Test'
$destino = 'C:\Test'

$word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

echo "Buscando cambios en las carpetas de origen..."

Get-ChildItem -Path $origen -Filter *.doc? | ForEach-Object {

    if (-Not (Test-Path "$destino\$($_.BaseName).pdf")) {
        $document = $word_app.Documents.Open($_.FullName)
        $pdf_filename = "$destino\$($_.BaseName).pdf"   
        echo "$($_.FullName) convertido a $pdf_filename!"
        $document.SaveAs([ref] $pdf_filename, [ref] 17)
        $document.Close()
    } 
}


$word_app.Quit()
```

---

Comment: I don't see any screenshots.

Comment: Something I'm not clear about: Can there be more than one instance of your script running at a time? If that's the case, then you will be doing multiple concurrent operations in Word, but Word is not designed for that. It can only do one thing at a time. Word is a single-user client application. It wasn't designed to be used as a server application that can handle multiple simultaneous requests. I recall that there is a Knowledge Base article from MS about this.

Comment: What account runs the task? Might try setting visibility to false so it starts the process but does try showing the window.

Comment: Add the administrator to *Logon as a batch job* per GPO. This may help.

Comment: The limitation on using Office COM objects in non desktop environments has been explained before: http://superuser.com/questions/730474/cant-create-a-com-object-in-a-powershell-script-running-as-a-scheduled-task

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely to be specific to MS Word, which isn't designed or supported to run in a non-interactive session. Best solution is to find some other way to do your PDF conversion.

See

- [How to convert Word (doc) to PDF from Windows command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/393118/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-from-windows-command-line)
- http://officetopdf.codeplex.com/releases/view/118190
- [Can't create a COM object in a powershell script running as a scheduled task](https://superuser.com/questions/730474/cant-create-a-com-object-in-a-powershell-script-running-as-a-scheduled-task)
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757