# Can't create a COM object in a powershell script running as a scheduled task

Tags: powershell, microsoft-access, windows-task-scheduler

I have a powershell script I'm trying to run as a scheduled task. Its purpose is to perform a nightly export from an Access database, then upload the exported flat files to an SFTP destination. The script works fine when I run it manually, but when I try to run it as a scheduled task, it fails. I've narrowed down the problem to a failure to create a COM object.

**What I'm Seeing**

I've done some logging on this, and I think I know what's going on; I just don't know how to fix it.

The offending line in my powershell script is `$Access = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application`. When I run the script manually, my Access COM object is created successfully. `$Access` is of type `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ApplicationClass`, as I'd expect.

If I run it as a scheduled task, running under my own permissions, the COM object isn't created; `$Access` is returned as `$null`, which causes any method calls against that object to fail.

I *can* get the COM object created successfully by checking "Run with highest privileges" in the Task Scheduler, but this creates another problem. My Access database uses linked tables on a network share, and by running as the local admin, I lose access to those tables because I'm no longer a domain user.

**My question**

Does anybody know why I can't seem to create a COM object when running this as a scheduled task under my own credentials? Is there any fix for it?

Failing that, any suggestions for fixing my permissions problem? It seems like I'm in a Catch-22 here; the only way to successfully create my COM object is to use credentials that cause the rest of my script to fail.

Comment: This answer is for excel, but it may help your situation with Access as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/13369587/291709 Also, be sure to check out the KB article on Server side considerations for office automation http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 Office applications assume a desktop environment, so running as a scheduled task while logged off can cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. After reading the KB article, I may consider an alternative way of doing this.

Comment: can you not map a drive to the network share in your script (including user credentials) so that local system can impersonate you while you are not logged in.   Maybe just need an `if test-path = false` statement followed by a `net use \\myshare` command to map it.