# Is there a way to search a folder for word documents then print those documents to PDFs?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, print-to-pdf

Basically i was wondering if there was a program that could search a main folder like "FolderA" containing "Folder1", "Folder2" and "Folder3" for word documents and print those documents to PDFs in the same folder the word file was in? So if "Word1.docx" and "Word2.docx" were in "Folder1" the program would find them and print "Word1.pdf" and "Word2.pdf" in "Folder1".

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator), it supports CLI options to be able to convert files to PDF. Couple this with a Batch script and you should be good to go!

Also, if setting the default printer in your machine to a PDF Printer, then you can just invoke below command to get the job done [[Ref](https://superuser.com/a/393121/122342)]. Again, this needs to be coupled with a batch script that can parse all files in the folder structure and trigger the command for all .docx files

```
"winword.exe" "C:\Folder1\Folder2\File1.docx" /mFilePrintDefault
```

There are other paid (or closed source) alternatives to the above options, but I prefer to use/suggest open/free solutions.

Comment: This works and I have been using another program called cutepdf, but you have to open each individual folder and select the word documents in that folder, print, then click ok to save each individual pdf. I was wondering if there was a way to select "FolderA" and say print to pdf. Then the program goes through all files that are word documents and prints them to pdf automatically. I haven't seen a program that does this.

Comment: You can achieve it using a batch file!

Comment: Oh ok. I will look into the script you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do it manually:

1. Install a PDF printer. PDFCreator installs a browser toolbar, so I'd go for Bullzip or another [alternative](http://alternativeto.net/software/pdfcreator/?license=free).
2. In Windows Exporer, go to the top level folder and search for docx files.
3. Ctrl+click all the documents you want to print.
4. Right click and select print.
5. Choose the PDF printer.

Comment: That's a good idea. I don't know why I didn't think of it. Thanks!